# Error in PreAuthorize annotation with hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

The `controller` in my application is mentioned below and I get the error when I try to start the Application:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/api/admin")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
class AdminController (private val userRepository: UserRepository, private val roleRepository: RoleRepository) {

    @GetMapping("/getUsers")
    fun getUsers(): List<UserResponseAdmin> {
        return userRepository.findAll().stream().map { user: User ->
            UserResponseAdmin(user)
        }.collect(Collectors.toList())
    }
}
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminController' defined in file [E:\_dev\appspring\target\classes\de\totwart\appspring\controller\AdminController.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class de.totwart.appspring.controller.AdminController: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class de.totwart.appspring.controller.AdminController
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at ...
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class de.totwart.apppongspring.controller.AdminController: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class de.totwart.apppongspring.controller.AdminController
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:209)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:478)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:342)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:291)
    at
```

When I remove the annotation, everything is working fine. I don't understand the issue. Why its saying that I am using a final class, when I don't.

Any Ideas, what I can try?

PS: found the solution.
@PreAuthorize maybe extends the AdminController, so AdminController must be "open"

open class AdminController

Comment: try after putting `public` access modifier on class and method

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Java, **all classes in Kotlin are by default closed or final.**

Why does this matter when you add the @PreAuthorize ? - well, what Spring does is inject some behaviour around the method to enforce the check.  That is implemented by subclassing your original class, hence the need for your class to be **open**.  Many other parts of the Spring framework use this same subclassing technique, so it is a very common requirement to need to open all your Controller and similar classes.

As you found yourself, adding the `open` keyword fixes this but you can make a project-wide change if you simply include a special dependency called Kotlin-Allopen.  Find out more here: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/allopen-spring